# Can I set the vim colorscheme from the command line?

Tags: bash, vim, ssh, colors, terminal

I have a hotkey set to automatically create some aliases and install a script whenever I SSH into a server (for my work). Does anyone know of a way to set the vim colo from the command line so I can use it in my hotkey? Thank you!

Comment: If you're installing scripts, why not add the color scheme to `$HOME/.vimrc`?

Comment: The strangest thing, but the servers I'm SSH'ing into don't have a vimrc. They have vim installed, and a .viminfo, but no .vimrc. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: It just means that nobody has created one yet!  Not all dot config files come with defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run commands when starting vim:

```
vim +'colorscheme blue' my_file
```

See `man vim`:

```
   -c {command}
       {command}  will  be  executed after the first file has been read.
       {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.  If the {command} contains 
       spaces it must be enclosed in double quotes (this depends on the shell 
       that is used). Example: Vim "+set si" main.c
       Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I can use this to make an alias like so: alias vim="vim +'colo elflord'". Didn't think about the possibility of using an appended command.

Comment: @Egrodo if you want to set the colorscheme everytime you open vim, then you should add the line to your vimrc file. See `$ vim '+help vimrc'`